# Play mp4 in Safari and deactivate loop of swf

Tags: video, safari, flash, html5-video, mp4

I'm trying to make a video element compatible for all browsers. VideoForEverybody is working in all browsers.

The only problem is that **Safari doesn't recognize the mp4 file** (VideoForEveryBody says it should) and **plays the swf** file.

This is a problem because **in Safari the swf file is played in infinite loop**, though I didn't add the loop-attribute. Deactivating the loop with `$("#videoTag").prop('loop', false);` didn't help.

```
<video id="videoTag"  width="800" height="600" preload="auto" autoplay="none">
 <source src="videos/test.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
 <source src="videos/test.ogv" type="video/ogg" />
 <object   width="800" height="600"   type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="videos/test.swf">
   <param name="flashvars" value="controlbar=over&amp;image=videos/loader-bar-video.gif&amp;file=videos/test.mp4" />
    <img src="videos/test.jpg"   alt="videoName" title="No video playback capabilities, please download the video below" />
 </object>
</video>
```

So the solution could be either to

- make the mp4 work in Safari or
- deactivate the loop

Someone has an idea how to do this?

Safari and Adobe Flash Player are up-to-date.

Answer (score 0):

In flashvars replace '&amp;' with '&'. The example at VfE page seemed to have been inadvertently filtered (HTML escaped) so the ampersands were translated to HTML ampersand entities. According to Adobe docs, key-value pairs of variables introduced via flashvars are delimited by ampersand characters.